# Проверить сходимость итерационного процесса

Tags: c++, c, математика

Есть вот такой код, который ищет корни методом простых итераций:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#define pi 3.14

double f(double x) {
     return   x*x-(cos(pi*x));
}

double fi(double x, double L) {
    return  x+L*f(x);
}


int main() {
    int n=0;
    double x,y,c,b,L=-0.35,eps;
    cout<<"x="; cin>>x;
    cout<<"eps="; cin>>eps;
    do {
        y=fi(x,L);
        b=fabs(x-y);
        x=y;
        n+=1;
    }
    while (b>=eps);
        cout<<"c="<<x<<"\n";
        cout<<"n="<<n<<"\n";
        getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вычитал следующее:

> Сходимость итерационного процесса означает, что погрешность каждого последующего приближения должна быть меньше погрешности предыдущего приближения, т.е. погрешность приближенных значений с каждым шагом должна уменьшаться: |x*-xk+1|<|x*-xk|

Как я понял, я просто должен проверять меньше ли текущий X по сравнению с предыдущим?
Как я понимаю, если итерационный процесс расходится, то я должен уходить из цикла?

Нужно ли вводить какое-нибудь ко-во попыток, что бы удостовериться, что идет расхождение?

Comment: Это вопрос не к нам, а к вашему лектору. В любом случае, у вас ведь _нету_ точного значения `x` (вы его как раз вычисляете), так что смысл определения чисто математический.

Answer (score 2):

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) есть картинка по сходимости метода простой итерации (нарисуйте её для своего случая) и вывод по теме:  "Таким образом, угловой коэффициент не должен быть слишком мал по абсолютной величине: при малом угловом коэффициенте уже на первом шаге точка  может выскочить из рассматриваемой окрестности корня, и сходимости к корню может не быть".

Но это в принципе. А в Вашем случае лучше "текущий по сравнению с предыдущим".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]